# How to create a graph with 2 complimentary seriesItem using DecoView lib

Tags: android, graph

I am trying to create a wheel graph which shows 2 complementary seriesItem for example (red line 80%, blue line 20% ) which always add up to 100% of the graph.

In [DecoView](https://github.com/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/blob/master/README.md) Github repo I found an [example](https://github.com/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hookedonplay/decoviewsample/SamplePeopleFragment.java) similar to what I want but I am not able to reconstruct that graph again.

Here is [video](https://youtu.be/nycmNd7FQDM) of that example in action  @1:30

If someone can help me out and break it down for me, because there isn't much documentation for this lib

I am only able to add 2 independent seriesItems but not complementary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the People sample the series are animated at the same time to give the impression the second series is pushing the first series along. This is done using a series of timed events.

At 3 seconds `series1` is animated to 19%, then after 11 seconds `series2` starts animating to 45% and at the same time `series1` animates to 64%. This means that `series1` will be pushed along and occupy the same 19% of the chart that is visible. The other 45% of `series1` is now covered by `series2`.

Here is the code from SamplePeopleFragment.java that sets up these events:

```
addAnimation(arcView, mSeries1Index, 19, 3000, imgView, R.drawable.ic_avatar_man, COLOR_BLUE);
addAnimation(arcView, mSeries2Index, 45, 11000, imgView, R.drawable.ic_avatar_woman, COLOR_PINK);

arcView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(64)
        .setIndex(mSeries1Index)
        .setDelay(11000)
        .setDuration(5000)
        .build());
```

The `addAnimation` function does a few things like animating image fades, you are just interested in the following part of the function that sets up the animated series move:

```
arcView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(moveTo)
        .setIndex(series)
        .setDelay(delay)
        .setDuration(5000)
        .setListener(listener)
        .build());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro I was having a hard time trying to make sense of the sample, if you could implement this in your lib and make it work out of the box that would be great. Also thanks for answering me on youtube too lol.

Comment: @RootOfMinusOne I'll be doing a V2.0 of DecoView later in the year, so will put this on the 'New features to consider' list. Thanks for your input